# Academic name of dataset preparation method with hierarchical-learned labels? - E.g., cold→half-cooked→cooked

Tags: classification, data-cleaning, preprocessing, multilabel-classification, fuzzy-logic

What's the name of the dataset preparation method indicating hierarchical ontologies?

Assume photos of cold, half-cooked, and fully-cooked chickens. Annotate with temperature data. E.g., at current temperature the half-cooked photo will become fully-cooked in 20 minutes.

For training the ML model say you removed one or both of the labels from each image; and furthermore shuffled the chickens at each stage.

Does this approach have a name in the literature? - Like *fuzzy hierarchical label learning* or something fancy like that?

Comment: Shuffling is the norm. What would be the purpose of removing the labels? What would the model be predicting?

Comment: @noe - Model would predict both temperature and one of "cold", "half-cooked", "fully-cooked". But one might want to predict the chance that cold becomes half-cooked based on temperature. And one might infer both labels based on photo.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, your labels could be classified as ordinal data. I think so because they are categories with some particular order - less or more baked chicken. Thus, the name of the task you are looking for could be [**ordinal regression** or **ordinal classification**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression). I found a nice research using CNN (but there is a plethora of them) in an ordinal problem and it even has a comparison to a plain classification approach:

Rosati, R., Romeo, L., Vargas, V. M., Gutiérrez, P. A., Hervás-Martínez, C., & Frontoni, E. (2022). A novel deep ordinal classification approach for aesthetic quality control classification. Neural Computing and Applications, 34(14), 11625-11639.

You can start from this one. I hope you find it helpful.